# What was the 2016 presidential scandal in South Korea about?

Tags: impeachment, south-korea, scandal, summary-request

In 2016, the president of South Korea, Park Geun-hye, was [caught up in a scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_of_Park_Geun-hye) with allegations of her being controlled by a religious cult.

I have also heard rumours of her jailing or otherwise silencing people who tried speaking up about this before the matter came to light. Can anyone give me a rundown of this bizarre event and its consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best source of information I know is a blog by an American/Korean called [Ask a Korean](https://askakorean.blogspot.com). Doing a search in that site for the word 'impeachment' gives quite a few posts about this, with a lot of detail.

The very short version is that President Park (before she was president) came 'under the influence' of a cult leader, Choi Tae-min, who claimed he could talk with Park's dead mother. His daughter, Choi Soon-sil, became a close friend and took as much advantage of that as she could.

I'm not sure about getting people sent to jail, but suing for defamation and getting people fired certainly happened along with an astonishing amount of theft and improper influence. A good place to start is [this post (Part 1)](https://askakorean.blogspot.com/2016/11/the-ultimate-choi-soon-sil-gate.html) and its [Part 2](https://askakorean.blogspot.com/2016/12/the-ultimate-choi-soon-sil-gate.html).